# Oracle start and end position of string function

Tags: string, oracle, function

I'm looking to create a function where I pass in a string and it returns the start and end position of the string along with the pattern I'm searching for. Would instrr be the correct command to use?

```
create table data(
 str VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT into data (id,str) VALUES (1,'123hellphello321hello64');

Expected outcome 
 start_pos end_pos str
 9 13 hello
 16 20 hello
```

Comment: Oracle already invented this wheel: `INSTR('...', 'hello')` and `INSTR('...', 'hello', -1)`. Oh, and `LENGTH('hello')`. Why would you have it return the string youre looking for; you already know it?

Comment: To make sure I found the correct result. In addition, I want to know how to pull the VALUES from the string. Also I want to handle multiple occurrences of the value in the string

Comment: Pretty sure INSTR finds as Oracle promise it will.. I'd say the chance of it finding `hello` at pos 1 in your string there are just about 0, for example

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot. I was looking at the like command but I want something a bit smarter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSTR` in a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH search (term) AS (
  SELECT 'hello' FROM DUAL
),
rsqfc (id, start_pos, end_pos, str, term) AS (
  SELECT id,
         INSTR(str, term, 1),
         INSTR(str, term, 1) + LENGTH(term),
         str,
         term
  FROM   data
         CROSS JOIN search
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         INSTR(str, term, end_pos),
         INSTR(str, term, end_pos) + LENGTH(term),
         str,
         term
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  start_pos > 0
)
SELECT *
FROM   rsqfc
WHERE  start_pos > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table data(id, str) AS
SELECT 1, '123hellphello321hello64' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | START_POS | END_POS | STR | TERM |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 9 | 14 | 123hellphello321hello64 | hello |
> | 1 | 17 | 22 | 123hellphello321hello64 | hello |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f0c8608bc62abeccd15be59cd34829e6)*

Comment: @MTO thanks. I was killing myself trying to turn this into a generic function by playing with TYPES and was going no where fast

Answer (score 0):

You can also take advantage of the **return_option** option of the ***regexp_instr*** function as below.
[regexp_instr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions129.htm)

```sql
with YourTable (id, c) as (
  select 1, '123hellphello321hello64' from dual
)
, search (term) as (
  select 'hello' from dual
)
, rws (lvl) as (
  select level from dual 
  connect by level <= (
    select max(regexp_count(t.c, s.term)) from YourTable t cross join search s )
)
select t.id, t.c
  , regexp_instr(t.c, s.term, 1, rws.lvl, 0) start_pos
  , regexp_instr(t.c, s.term, 1, rws.lvl, 1) end_pos
  , s.term
from YourTable t 
cross join search s
join rws on rws.lvl <= regexp_count(t.c, s.term)
order by t.id, rws.lvl
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5a73ab5524a190c3b29bb20d5903f86)

Comment: thank you for responding and your eloquent solution. Would this be better as a generic function or procedure where it could be wrapped by a clob, VARCHAR2.. and could be used by passing some string and a search term. That's my ultimate goal so it could be used in many places without anything hard coded such as table or column names. I was thinking maybe a function returns a type start_pos, end_pos, result? Does that make sense?

Comment: You're welcome.
But, such function could return more than one row. So would you want its return value to be grouped as a list of : start_pos_1, end_pos_1 ; start_pos_2, end_pos_2 ; start_pos_3, end_pos_3, ... ?

Comment: correct. I was thinking returning start_pos, end_pos, match. Passing in a CLOB, VARCHAR2 any string from column along with a word or phrase to be matched. Sort of like how stackoverflow works by finding a tag and returns all the matches. The function or procedure should be able to be used any where in an Oracle DB, where a user has permission to SELECT from the data. Hopefully this makes sense